# buffer overflow with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a problem using boost:program_options

this simple program, copy-pasted from boosts' documentation :

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

fails with a buffer overflow.

I have activated the "buffer security switch", and when I run it I get an "unknown exception (0xc0000409)" when I step over the line `desc.add_options()...`

I use Visual Studio 2005 and boost 1.43.0.

By the way it does run if I deactivate the switch but I don't feel comfortable doing so... unless it's possible to deactivate it locally.

So do you have a solution to this problem?

**EDIT**
I found the problem
I was linking against libboost_program_options-vc80-mt.lib which wasn't the good library.

Comment: Can you add what version of boost you are using?

Comment: I added it. It's version 1.43.0

Comment: You don't need to manually link in VS.  Boost uses the pragma directives to link.

Comment: yes, I figured that out after adding "libboost_program_options-vc80-mt.lib" to the list and I forgot to remove it, especially after I changed the runtime library to Multithread DLL!

Comment: You should add your realization as an answer, F4. In a day or two, you can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I was linking against libboost_program_options-vc80-mt.lib which wasn't the good library since I changed the runtime library to Multithread DLL.

Answer (score 1):

It works in 2010.  Was about to try in 2005 but realized I don't have 1.43 compiled in that environment.